# DHT22 and ESP32 - Humidity is not working and wrong temperature

Tags: arduino, esp32

I am trying to get a values from DHT22 sensor (https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32893654102.html?spm=a2g0s.9042311.0.0.1fae4c4dSLLDyP), which is connected to my ESP32 board, but even from example program, I am getting NaN from humidity function and temperatures around -3200 C.

Here is code

```
#include "DHT.h"
#define DHTPIN 4
#define DHTTYPE DHT22 

DHT dht(DHTPIN, DHTTYPE);

void setup() {
 Serial.begin(9600);
 Serial.println("DHTxx test!");

 dht.begin();
}

void loop() {
 delay(2000);
 float h = dht.readHumidity();
 float t = dht.readTemperature();

 Serial.print("Humidity: ");
 Serial.print(h);
 Serial.print(" %\t");
 Serial.print("Temperature: ");
 Serial.print(t);
 Serial.println(" *C");
}
```

Do you have any idea, why is this happening? Do I have wrong piece or something?
Thanks for your advices.

Comment: Do you have a pull-up resistor between input pin and Vcc?

Comment: I think that resistor should be soldered on board

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the correct answer, but I will explain and you could test it. I don't have a DHT22 with me but if my memory is correct on my previous use of DHT22 on Arduino that DHT22 is a very slow sensor (take up 250mS) to get the temperature data. So I would suggest to modified your program slight:

```
void loop() {
 float h = dht.readHumidity();
 float t = dht.readTemperature();

 // Check if any reads failed and exit to try again
 if (isnan(h) || isnan(t)) {
   delay(10);   // you can fine tune this delay
   return;
 }

 Serial.print("Humidity: ");
 Serial.print(h);
 Serial.print(" %\t");
 Serial.print("Temperature: ");
 Serial.print(t);
 Serial.println(" *C");
 delay(2000);
}
```

Comment: It helped, kinda... Humidity now work, but functions are returning insane numbers... (-3200 C and 6500 %)

Answer (score 1):

I know that this is an old post, but I'm seeing this very question over and over, so I thought that I'd put in my 12 cents (no longer 2 cents... inflation you know!  LOL)

The problem is reading too fast and too often.

I ran into these same problems when I first started using DHT22 sensors.  But I learned.

You see, in reality, we don't NEED to be reading the sensor values so fast.

In void loop()  I set up a timer that triggers every 5 or 10 seconds.  I then put the sensor read code onto its own tab to make troubleshooting easier.

I only allow the timer to trigger a read and nothing else.  There's no reason to.

At the top of the sketch, I create global float variables as follows
tempRead
humidRead
prevTempRead
preHumidRead
averageTemp
averageHumid

I use the prev variables so as to save code time by not processing temp or humd UNLESS either have changed.

As for the NAN error checking, I use NOT there, so the code only uses data IF there is NOT a NAN returned.

Then, once a temp or humid is read from the DHT22, I'll do something like:

so I'll create an if statement to compare the temperature (and humidity later) from the prev. value:
prevTempRead != tempRead

then here I'll use an "averaging" variable to create an average of a bunch of reads.  Depending on the time between reads, I'll use a counter of perhaps 10 or 20 or even 50 to get a nice, clean average.

Do the same for humidity.

So then, only when the average variables change, do I allow other code to grab the updated numbers.

Since doing things this way, to date, I've not had a single problem.  And I do use the DHT22 for both Arduino and ESP32.
With the ESP32, in fact, I'm using several boards in a Peer-to-Peer method (rather than going through WiFi).

This all works nicely without any glitching.

So the 2 secrets are, don't read fast and often.  There really is no need for that.

Once you have your tab set up (or just a function in main code if you like) then just call that through a timer of 5 to 10 seconds (or longer if you don't need updates that soon).

While you COULD just do this without globals (basic reads) I find that using the globals to compare and average returns really nice, solid numbers that don't "jitter" out of control like I saw when I first started using DHT22 shields.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Both @BlondieSL and @hcheung are correct, DHTs are pants and notoriously slow with one nice feature and that is when you read them too fast they can overheat and can read their own temperature or some nonsense or in some cases cook themselves.

From experience the absolute minimum read time should be no less than 3 seconds and the sweet spot I've found is about 10sec read interval.

Also, definitely do the NaN check

Same rule applies to AHT sensors.

And one word of wisdom (that I've learned the hard way) keep them well away from the main board/chip if you are putting them in some enclosure.
Best way is to the side and below the level of the main chip/board, hot air goes up so your sensor could be reading your main chip's temp if it's above or generally the conditions inside the case (gives a nice never changing temp and low humidity though:-)